# how to return object of inner class from outer class

Tags: java

*in class main I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException*

```
class Outer {
    Outer() {
    }

    class Inner {
        Inner() {
        }
    }

    public Inner func() {
        Outer.Inner type = this.new Inner();  // this is correct or not ?? 
        return type;  //I want to return this object
    }
}
```

*my  problem in  public Inner func(A a) or not ???*

*in Class main I define*

```
    Outer O = new Outer();
    Outer.Inner t;
    t = O.func(); //**I get Exception Her**
```

Comment: Where is `object_of_A` defined? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: All of your code looks correct except `object_of_A` isn't initialized anywhere.

Comment: Did not matter
I am not put all my code her

Comment: object_of_A defined in func2()

Comment: What I care about is public Inner func(A a)

Comment: I want to return type in public Inner func(A a) correctly

Comment: I facilitated my code for my interests
Good now ??

Comment: [This code works fine.](https://ideone.com/hjMRTQ) Again, please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: My problem is Solved 
The problem was not in this code above

Comment: I thank everyone for verifying the code above